# algorithm: partition 2 arrays into "only in A", "intersection of A & B", & "only in B"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a situation where I have two arrays and I need to partition them so that I end up with 3 arrays:

- elements that are only in A
- elements that are only in B
- elements that are in both A and B

Example:

```
A = [1, 4, 3, 2]
B = [2, 6, 5, 3]
3part(A,B) => [[1,4], [6,5], [2,3]] # the order of the elements in each array doesn't matter
```

I've come up with a correct solution, but wonder if it could be quicker. It is (in pseudocode):

```
3part(A,B) =>
    a_only = []
    b_only = []
    intersect = []

    foreach a in A
        if B.contains(a)
            intersect.push(a)
        else
            a_only.push(a)

    foreach b in B
        if not intersect.contains(b)
            b_only.push(b)

    return [a_only, b_only, intersect]
```

In my case at hand, A & B will each contain up to 5000 complex structures (instead of ints) and it runs in about 1.5 secs. It gets used as part of a user interaction which can happen frequently, so ideally it would take < .5sec .

BTW, is there a name for this operation as a whole, other than "difference-difference-intersection"?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the suggestions to use a hash, my updated code runs in under 40ms :-D

Here is the pseudocode:

(say that "key" is the element that I am using for comparison)

```
array_to_hash(A, Key)
    h = {}
    foreach a in A
        h[a[Key]] = a
    return h

3part(A,B) =>
    a_only = []
    b_only = []
    intersect = {} // note this is now a hash instead of array

    Ah = array_to_hash(A, 'key')
    Bh = array_to_hash(B, 'key')

    foreach ak in Ah.keys()
        if Bh.hasKey(ak)
            intersect[ak] = Ah[ak]
        else
            a_only.push(Ah[ak])

    foreach bk in Bh.keys()
        if not intersect.hasKey(bk)
            b_only.push(Bh[bk])

    return [a_only, b_only, intersect.values]
```

Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: Can you use multi-threading? Both for loops can be done in parallel, but care has to be taken when doing `intersect.push(...)`.

Comment: If you sort A and B before, you would not need to do a linear search on each one for each one (Use a binary search) .

Comment: @RomainHippeau Assuming the data set is sortable, `<` and `>` might not make any sense for the data structure.

Comment: @pingul It is sortable, if it does not have a name or other value he can sort on, maybe the reference in memory ?

Comment: I like this and yes it is sortable. I'll see if I can bust that out sometime today. Thanks!

Comment: @RomainHippeau That's a valid point. Just to clarify, the binary search would be beneficial for the `.contains(...)` operations, right? Sounds like a good candidate for an answer.

Comment: @RomainHippeau: yes, that should be an answer.

Comment: thanks to whoever made the calling example to "code style", that looks much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense that you're allowing yourself to be handicapped by assumptions of primitive operations.  Current hardware includes excellent hashing support and GEMM operations.

1. Hash the values of A and B into a single space, with a range on the order of |A + B|.
2. Convert both arrays to one-hot encoding in that range.
3. Apply vector AND-OR-NOT operations to obtain your three results.

Comment: Prune, your suggestion got me going with the hash idea. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Your pseudocode is good IF you use a hashed set data structure for all the "arrays".

I guess all current programming environments have decent collections support, including hash-based sets. Here are two examples how to do it in Java, running in more or less O(n+m). In Java, for hashed collections to function properly, it's important that your complex objects implement the `hashCode()` and the `equals()` method in a compliant fashion (can often be auto-generated by your IDE).

The first version completely relies on the set-algebra implementation of your library, which should result in O(n) if the library is OK:

```
private static void test1() {
    Integer[] a = {1, 4, 3, 2};
    Integer[] b = {2, 6, 5, 3};

    Set<Integer> aOnly = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    Set<Integer> bOnly = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b));

    Set<Integer> ab = new HashSet<>(aOnly);
    ab.retainAll(bOnly);
    aOnly.removeAll(ab);
    bOnly.removeAll(ab);

    System.out.println("A only: " + aOnly);
    System.out.println("A and B: " + ab);
    System.out.println("B only: " + bOnly);
}
```

The second one uses the fact that in Java, the remove() method returns true if the element was present before removing it. If your library doesn't do that you have to

```
private static void test2() {
    Integer[] a = {1, 4, 3, 2};
    Integer[] b = {2, 6, 5, 3};

    Set<Integer> aOnly = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    Set<Integer> bOnly = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> ab = new HashSet<>();

    for (int bElem : b) {
        if (aOnly.remove(bElem)) {
            ab.add(bElem);
        } else {
            bOnly.add(bElem);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("A only: " + aOnly);
    System.out.println("A and B: " + ab);
    System.out.println("B only: " + bOnly);
}
```

Comment: very similar to what I came up with, minus taking advantage of element deletion. Thank You for your suggestion! I will try out using delete and see how that works.

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are sortable then you could do 2 things

1. to check if a value is in the other array, simply do a binary search on the other array, Complexity O(nlogm + mlogn)
2. Or you could merge arrays into the 3 arrays using 2 pointers, since the arrays are sorted, if the first elements are equal add them to the intersection set, incase they are not if element in A < element in B. add the element in A to the array a[] and now check the 2nd element with the first element in B. 
   same if B was less than A 
   Complexity O(n + m).
   you can maintain which element we are referring to using 2 pointers

Comment: +1. Note that you can use option #2 with array-indices rather than actual *pointers*, if desired (e.g. if your language doesn't support pointer arithmetic).

Comment: I was going to run with this idea, similar to ideas suggested by RomainHipeau and pingul until the hash based solutions were suggested. I still want to code this up, but I'm sure it will take more effort than the hash-based solution. Thank You!